# grails gorm how to use length function

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I am trying to translate this sql into grails GORM, but not sure how to use length function.

this is the SQL I need

```
select * from  stats where length(hostname) <=0 order by hostname limit 1,10
```

I tried with http://grails.org/doc/2.2.1/ref/Domain%20Classes/createCriteria.html createCriteria but it giving me the error message.

how can I translate this SQL to GORM query.

```
def c = Status.createCriteria()
def results = c.list (max: 10, offset: 10) {
                 length("hostname") <=0
              }
results.each{println it}
```

**error message**

```
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: grails.orm.HibernateCriteriaBuilder.length() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [hostname]
Possible solutions: getAt(java.lang.String), select(java.lang.String), avg(java.lang.String), count(java.lang.String), gt(java.lang.String, java.lang.Object), gte(java.lang.String, java.lang.Object)
```

this HSQL works:

```
def results = Status.findAll("from Status as b where " +
                              "length(b.hostname) <= 0 " +
                              "order by b.hostname asc",
                              [max: 10, offset: 20])
```

1. how we use createCriteria for this?
2. Which one better createCriteria or HSQL?

thanks

Comment: Congrats. You are on right track (encouraging me not to feed the answer ready made). As I mentioned earlier, have a look at `sqlRestriction` in criteria docs again. You are an inch far from getting success using criteria. :) To answer your second question, I would prefer HQL as you saw it was easy for you and moreover a Criteria query in converted to HQL when executed. But again do visit `sqlRestriction`, do not leave that stone unturned.